# return auto filter criteria in another cell using google sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets, autofilter

I'm trying to return the current selected auto-filter criteria of a column in a different cell.

eg:

```
   A
1 COLOURS
2 red
3 green 
4 blue

      A         B         C
1 COLOURS               green  
3 green
```

So if 'green' in 'colours' is filtered, C1 will show green.

In excel, I achieved what I needed using the following array forumla, where Coloumn 'I' was filtered:

> =INDEX(I1:I330,MIN(IF(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($I$5:I330,ROW($I$5:I330)-MIN(ROW($I$5:I330)),,1))<>0,SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($I$5:I330,ROW($I$5:I330)-MIN(ROW($I$5:I330)),,1))*ROW($I$5:I330))))

This formula doesn't work in google sheets...

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: ####### `C1=A3` ?

Comment: Yes... except when the auto filter is changed, C1 will still show A3, not what the new AF criteria is. (or the first visible cell of the newly filtered array)

Comment: What is the exact case scenario?  Sheets provide inbuilt `FILTER` function. Have you tried that?  Also, Try enclosing your formula with `ARRAYFORMULA()`

Comment: I tried enclosing within an array, but that didn't work.

I've created an example spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1srMADaFcBWPanaLg2mdgfcEHrnq1ZxasIy-8thbR3GU/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a hidden column: B1:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(A1:A10))
```

Then, C1(or D1):

```
=OFFSET(A1,SUBTOTAL(5,B2:B9)-1,)
```